# Let $B(n)$ be the number of bit strings that contain “$01$” derive a recurrence relation for $B(n)$ and solve iteratively

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, bit-strings

I believe I have found the recurrence relation to be
$$B\left(n\right)=B\left(n-1\right)+2^{n-1}-1$$
with Initial Condition $B(0)=0$ (I am a bit unsure about the initial condition though but I think it is correct)

Now I am trying to solve $B(n)$ using iteration, this is what I have so far:
$$B\left(n\right)=B\left(n-1\right)+2^{n-1}-1$$
$$B\left(n\right)=B\left(n-2\right)+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}-\left(2\right)1$$
$$B\left(n\right)=B\left(n-3\right)+2^{n-3}+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}-\left(3\right)1$$
$$=B\left(n-k\right)+2^{n-k}+2^{n-\left(k-1\right)}+2^{n-\left(k-2\right)}-\left(k\right)1$$
and then I let n=k since the intial condition is $B(0)$ but this is where I get confused I am not sure what to do from here?
$$=B\left(0\right)+2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^{\left(?\right)}-n$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $B_0=B_1=0$.  Let $A_n = 2^n - B_n$ be the number of bit strings that do *not* contain $01$, so $A_0=1$.  For $n>1$, condition on whether the first bit is $0$ or $1$ to obtain recurrence relation
$$A_n = 1 + A_{n-1},$$
which implies that
$$A_n = n+1.\tag1$$
Hence
$$B_n = 2^n - A_n = 2^n - (1 + A_{n-1}) = 2^n - 1 - (2^{n-1} - B_{n-1}) = 2^{n-1} - 1 + B_{n-1},$$
or just use $(1)$ to conclude that $B_n = 2^n - n - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You’re on the right track:

$$\begin{align*}
B(n)&=B(n-1)+2^{n-1}-1\\
&=B(n-2)+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}-2\\
&=B(n-3)+2^{n-3}+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}-3\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=B(n-k)-k+\sum_{i=1}^k2^{n-i}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=B(0)-n+\sum_{i=1}^n2^{n-i}\\
&=-n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i\\
&=-n+2^n-1\\
&=2^n-n-1\,.
\end{align*}$$